# TypeError: __webpack_require__.i(...) is not a function on moment function

Tags: reactjs

i have got error on moment module when loading the first page of the  react app.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What moment version are you using. People have reported similar issue with a specific moment version. Please refer to below link on more details
https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/4223

Also if you are using dynamic import within your code this error can occur. Please take a look at "dynamic-import-node".

Comment: how can i check my moment version

Comment: take a look at package.json file. There you will find moment version.

Comment: can you change that to 2.18.1 remove ^. Do npm install and run webpack again

Comment: so you mean that i have to reinstall moment module again?

Comment: ^2.18.1 means it will bump to the next minor version automatically. What I am asking is change that to 2.18.1 which means install this specific version. Do a npm install and check if it is working.